# ASP.net Forms Authentication Issue When User Logs into the site as 'www.thedomain.com' vs. 'thedomain.com'

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I have a 3.5 .net site running forms authentication on a folder named "portal".  Once the person has logged in successfully all code runs from within that folder, and everything works very well.

However I recently installed sigma grid and it uses a JSON type call to data.aspx to populate the grid.  It worked just fine until a client tried to log in by going to mydomain.com vs. www.mydomain.com.

Because the JSON call in the javascript says to pull data from http://www.mydomain.com/portal/data.aspx vs. http://mydomain.com/portal/data.aspx the call fails since they are logged in via mydomain.com vs. www.mydomain.

I'm wondering if there is a way to tell .net that either with or without the www is ok after successful authentication has occurred.  I could also control the login page and put in 301's to make sure they only can log in via the www, but that caused some other issues that I haven't quite figured out yet.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Switching to 4.0 and using the URL Rewrite Module with "canonial hostname rewrite rule" is no option?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to set up the cookies so they work in subdomains and IE which can be fickle (www acting as a subdomain or mydomain.com in this example).

Inside your web.config in  put:

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="false" domain=".mydomain.com"/>
```

Here's more information http://philosophil.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!7E55D8EFA2AEE5D6!183.entry